# There was an error getting information about "/" while copying to desktop

Tags: shortcuts

Currently running Ubuntu 13.10 after a fresh install/re install due to this problem.

The error occurs whenever I try to drag a file from the Ubuntu search( in the launcher ), to the desktop. the whole error message is as follows...

"Error while copying.
 There was an error getting information about “/”."

Show more details reveals the following...

"The specified location is not supported"

[image: Error when trying to drag an application to create a shortcut in destop]

I don't understand the problem and can't see any clear way of fixing it. Any and all advice would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

currently a bug -

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1241972

In the meantime just browse to the location of the .desktop(s) & copy and paste to your Desktop (typically /usr/share/applications