# How to find the path of a file found in Unity's Dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

Let's say that, for example, I want to have Firefox on my desktop. Due to [this bug](https://askubuntu.com/q/364005/186076), I can't just search for Firefox in the Dash and drag it onto my desktop. The proposed solution was to simply copy/paste the file. However, I just can't figure out how to do that.

I can search "Firefox" in the Dash and see the "Firefox Web Browser" application. However, when I right click it, it just opens a little dialog with an "uninstall" and "launch" option. I see no way to actually find out where the file is in order to copy and paste it to my desktop.

How can I find the path of an item (or open the item's location) that was found by searching the Dash?

Comment: I can tell you where it is, not necessarily how to find it from the dash though.. Take a look in `/usr/share/applications`. It should be a `.desktop` file. Probably `firefox.desktop`. But then I must ask, why do you want desktop icons? Those are so Windows :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly from the dash you can't, in fact there's no call in place that allows you to do this. GNOME 3 doesn't either. So, where are these values stored? They are normally called "application.desktop" so to copy these to the desktop you only need:

```
➜  ~  locate gparted.desktop ## Find where it's
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/gparted.desktop
/usr/share/applications/gparted.desktop # This is the default path for installed applications 
➜  ~  cp /usr/share/applications/gparted.desktop ~/Desktop # Done
```

This will make a copy on the desktop of the `.desktop` file, and should be interpreted as a "shortcut" to the program.

More about this in the specification page for .desktop files: http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ape.html

Answer (score 1):

Did some searching and came to the conclusion that this is, in fact, a bug in Unity and has been acknowledged by the Ubuntu developers - however, it doesn't seem as if anyone is currently working on it. Read more [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/798445).